# how to provide password to URL of Website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, passwords

I am uploading my website to server by random url to show my website to other but I want to password protected url .IF any one click on link then it need to show the login box like username and password .

I created it by htaccess tools.so it provide me `.htaccess` authentication and `.htpasswd`

here is my .htaccess authentication

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /home2/ravsnyk/public_html/blabla.com/beta/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

But there is already a some code in .htaccess file of wordpress.

Here is a code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blabla/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blablabla/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

so when i type my url and click on the enter so it not showing pop pup box and show 404 error message . please help me to find out the solution

Comment: To me it looks like your problem will be with `AuthUserFile`. Are you sure that is the correct path?

Comment: yes i create it by .htaccess tools